# Rails backend for an iOS app, twitter sign in

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, authentication, twitter, omniauth

I'm using omniauth-twitter for twitter log in to the website and it works perfectly well (go to /auth/twitter, user authenticates, and then redirect_to /auth/twitter/callback). Great.

However, on the iOS side, how can I implement sign in with twitter? Do I do it client side or server side? Could anybody go through the steps? (note: the only way to sign in to the app is through twitter)

We've tried:

- using a UIWebView that goes to /auth/twitter, but on redirect, it goes back to the web version. Is there a way to get JSON data from the UIWebView?
- doing sign in with twitter client side, and using a made up password to authenticate in sessions#create that matches a made up password on the db.

Is there another alternative for authentication? I know what we're doing has a lot of flaws but we couldn't find any other solutions even after asking in meetups and researching online for days. please help!

Comment: by 'client side' you mean the website or the app?

Comment: the app.. sorry about the misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

You could add an [OAuth 2](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749.txt) 
implementation on your server.  Your server authorizes the iOS app for an authenticated user / content owner.  (You have completed the authentication part.)  Once authorized, the iOS app accesses that particular user's content (via an api on your server) as if it is logged in as that user.

You will find one potential OAuth 2 provider implementation for RoR as
[applicake/doorkeeper](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper)

You will find a sample iOS client application as
[telegraphy-interactive/OAuthClientSetup](https://github.com/telegraphy-interactive/OAuthClientSetup)

That is one suggestion, in any case.  Not the whole answer, which would require a book chapter.